# How to convert data.frame to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, dataframe, spdf

Maybe it is something simple but I am stumped right now.
I have a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` which I extract the data columns and transform it into a standard `dataframe`. Then, I round the data. But, when I want to insert the data already rounded back into the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, I see that it keeps the data as it was originally, without being rounded. Here is my code.

```
Hex_Grid_Pop <- readOGR(dsn=".", layer="Hex_Grid_500_Pop")
df = as.data.frame(Hex_Grid_Pop)[, 3:13]
df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, round)
Hex_Grid_Pop[1:NROW(Hex_Grid_Pop), 3:13] = df
head(Hex_Grid_Pop@data)
```

[This is what my console shows me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBuLa.png) Sorry but I dont have the enough reputation to publish images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign `df` to `df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, round)`, i.e.

```
df <- df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, round)
```

Otherwise you `df` remained unchanged.

Also, nothing stops you from doing this:

```
Hex_Grid_Pop@data[,3:13] <- Hex_Grid_Pop@data[,3:13] %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, round)
```